# UITableView raises an "Could not load NIB in bundle" exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have deleted a UITableView from storyboard and created it programmatically.

I got below error:

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/zontragon/Library/Application   Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/478xxxx-AAxx-4xxx-90xx-7019xxxxx/album.app> (loaded)' with name 'tsO-ri-Bhf-view-e5d-Av-Ufv''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x030701e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02def8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0306ffbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   UIKit                               0x0218ab7b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 951
4   UIKit                               0x01ff36f5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
5   UIKit                               0x01ff3e9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
6   voguedrobe                          0x00020da0 -[VDMultiCategoryAlbumViewController loadView] + 64
```

I have created it like below:

```
// It gives exception below line.
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

I checked view controller's outlet's if there was a remain outlet. It was clear.

What would be the problem? Help please.

Comment: If you removed the tableView, you need to delete the app , clean project and run it again